# Centre Content Horizontally in Page

Tags: asp.net, css

I would like to display all my content in a div that is 800px wide, centred in the page. That way, all browser window widths are catered for. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your div CSS as follows:

```
#container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You will also need to set text-align:center; on your body tag otherwise it won't work for old versions of IE

Answer (score 4):

I would also recommend adding `text-align:left;` to the container div and adding `text-align:center;` to the body tag.  Reason being that Internet Explorer 6.0 will not handle the auto margins.

```
body {
      text-align:center;}

#container {
      margin: 0px auto;
      text-align:left;
      width: 800px;}
```